# ASP.NET MVC concatenate names and map to ID#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table which stores Person.  The attributes are `FirstName`, `LastName` and `PersonID`. I have added the attribute

```
public string NameFull { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
```

and I am able to display the output as a concatenated name.

However, when the user makes the selection of the name, I want to store it as the PersonID.

Currently, I have this as my linq Where statement:

```
var personID= db.Persons
         .Where(h => Names == model.Person.NameFull)
         .Select(h => h.PersonID);
var idToSave = personID.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().Trim().ToString();
```

In the controller:

```
SelectList names = new SelectList(db.Person.ToArray(), "PersonID", "NameFull");
ViewBag.Names = names;
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you want your PersonID to be? ´.Where()´ returns a collection, is this what you want?
Do you want to store it when the name is displayed?

Comment: Please provide more code. 
What is `Names`, `model` and `contactIDquery`, and where is this supposed to be saved?

Comment: So NameFull is the list of names that are in the table. I want to get the one name that is chosen by the user (implemented as a DropDownList)

Comment: Names is the ViewBag that I am using to display the output - will add to code.

Comment: Doesn't the DropDownList have a `.SelectedValue` property that gives you what you need?

Comment: How does the user make a selection? If is from a dropdownlist (as suggested by the use of `SelectList`), then bind it to a `PersonID` property so it submits the value (no need for a database call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Running Fiddle

Here is [a running fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u7gZhY) that I created for you. Select a person and click submit. The selected person's id will display after the HTTP post.

## Model

`MyViewModel` contains a `List` of persons and a `SelectedPersonID`. It is this view model that we bind to `DropDownListFor`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedPersonID { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID  { get; set; }
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Last { get; set; }

        public string NameFull
        {
            get {

                return First + " " + Last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## View

We bind the `DropDownListFor` to `MyViewModel`. Specifically, the first parameter is the current `SelectedPersonId`, and the second parameter is a new `SelectList` that we create from our view model.

```
@model HelloWorld.MyViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                m => m.SelectedPersonID, 
                new SelectList(Model.Persons, "PersonID", "NameFull"))
            <button type="sumbit">Submit</button>
        }
        <span>Selected Person's ID is @Model.SelectedPersonID</span>

    </body>
</html>
```

## Controller

On the post back to the controller, we can retrieve the `SelectedPersonID`.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public FakeDb fakeDb = new FakeDb();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = new MyViewModel {
                SelectedPersonID = fakeDb.Persons.FirstOrDefault().PersonID,
                Persons = fakeDb.Persons
            };

            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel vm)
        {
            // this is redundant 
            // but illustrates how to access the selected id  
            vm.SelectedPersonID = vm.SelectedPersonID;
            vm.Persons = fakeDb.Persons;

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

## FakeDb

This is just for demo purposes.

```
public class FakeDb
{
    public List<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            var persons = new List<Person>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                persons.Add(new Person()
                {
                    First = "First" + i, 
                    Last = "Last" + i, 
                    PersonID = i
                });
            }

            return persons; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then you want the first name and last name to be displayed in the dropdown and when a user selects a name combination, then the person's ID has to be used instead? If so, then the code below is based on my assumptions above.

I have created the necessary classes as what I would have done it. Please excuse if I have left something out, the code below is not tested.

Your `Person` class will look something like this:

```
public class Person
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public string FullName
     {
          get
          {
               return FirstName + " " + LastName;
          }
     }
}
```

I haven't worked with `Entity Framework` in ages, not sure if it will complain about `FullName` not being a column name in the persons table.

Create a `PersonViewModel` class that you will pass into the view.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
     public PersonViewModel()
     {
          Persons = new List<Person>();
     }

     public int PersonId { get; set; }

     public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you will have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel();

     // Get a list of all the people
     // I can't remember how to use Entity Framework to get a list of all the people,
     // it's something like the code below
     model.Persons = db.Persons;

     return View(model);
}
```

Your post action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonViewModel model)
{
     // Do whatever you need to do
}
```

In your view the code will look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.PersonId,
     new SelectList(Model.Persons, "Id", "FullName", Model.PersonId),
     "-- Select --"
)
```

The code above should display the first name and last name in the "text" part of the dropdown, and the ID of the person in the value of the dropdown.

I hope you come right :)